# Implementing non ViewGroup MVP Android View with Mosby

Tags: android, mvp, mosby

I'm trying to implement an MVP Android View (not activity or fragment) with Mosby, however when using the view within an Android Adaptor, and accessing it within an onBindViewHolder, the presenter is not initialized at this time.   It appears that the onAttachWindow is not called until after the onBindViewHolder is completed as the presenter is Null.   Here is the abstract class I have created.

```
public abstract class MvpImageView<V extends MvpView, P extends MvpPresenter<V>>
    extends AppCompatImageView implements MvpView, ViewGroupDelegateCallback<V, P> {

  protected P presenter;
  protected ViewGroupMvpDelegate<V, P> mvpDelegate;
  private boolean retainInstance = false;

  public MvpImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public MvpImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public MvpImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }

  /**
   * Get the mvp delegate. This is internally used for creating presenter, attaching and detaching
   * view from presenter etc.
   *
   * <p><b>Please note that only one instance of mvp delegate should be used per android.view.View
   * instance</b>.
   * </p>
   *
   * <p>
   * Only override this method if you really know what you are doing.
   * </p>
   *
   * @return {@link ViewGroupMvpDelegate}
   */
  @NonNull protected ViewGroupMvpDelegate<V, P> getMvpDelegate() {
    if (mvpDelegate == null) {
      mvpDelegate = new ViewGroupMvpDelegateImpl<>(this, this, true);
    }

    return mvpDelegate;
  }

  @Override protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Attaching to Window");
    getMvpDelegate().onAttachedToWindow();
  }

  @Override protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Detaching from Window");
    getMvpDelegate().onDetachedFromWindow();
  }

  @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall") @Override protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    return getMvpDelegate().onSaveInstanceState();
  }

  @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall") @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    getMvpDelegate().onRestoreInstanceState(state);
  }

  /**
   * Instantiate a presenter instance
   *
   * @return The {@link MvpPresenter} for this view
   */
  public abstract P createPresenter();

  @Override public P getPresenter() {
    return presenter;
  }

  @Override public void setPresenter(P presenter) {
    this.presenter = presenter;
  }

  @Override public V getMvpView() {
    return (V) this;
  }

  @Override public final Parcelable superOnSaveInstanceState() {
    return super.onSaveInstanceState();
  }

  @Override public final void superOnRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
  }
}
```

This is based off the MvpLinearLayout implementation.   I've used another MVP library in the past called Moxy and it had delegate methods for onCreate as well as onAttachToWindow.

I could add an initialization routine that call getMvpDelegate().onAttachWindow in the constructors but that seems more like a hack than anything else.   Any ideas on how to get this working when used within a onBindViewHolder and RecyclerView?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use MVP in your adapter. It just makes things over complicated and cumbersome to work with.

Example: Views / ViewHolder can be recycled, should Presenter be recycled too? If yes, how do you implement that and ensure that internal Presenter is fresh? How do you reattach Presenter to view while scrolling? What if your AdapterSet gets changed? What about screen orientation changes?

Simply don't do that.

Comment: So mosby mvp can be used with view, except when it the view has to be included in a a RecyclerView or an Adapter.  I would figure if a View or ViewHolder is recycled then a presenter redone as well at this point.  Another approach seems to be outlined here with the ViewHolder handling things, https://android.jlelse.eu/recyclerview-in-mvp-passive-views-approach-8dd74633158

Comment: In theory it can be used also in RecyclerView but the "lifecycle" of a View (onAttachToWindow() an onDetachToWindow()) are different from what you expect because you are thinking about ViewHolder "lifecycle" (onBindViewHolder() and onRecycleViewHolder() or something named like this ) are called later or earlier compared to View lifcycle. 

So if you really want to do the MVP thing in a RecyclerView (I think it is a big mistake) you should write your own thing that is using "ViewHolder lifecycle" rather than View lifecyclem

Comment: I'm just thinking of say a shopping cart application, where you may have a view within the shopping cart that needs to be more than a simple Display, but needs some interactivity, and needs dynamic updating.  Maybe I'll take a shot at this if so, I can always submit a pull request back for possible inclusion in the project.  It may end up being a MvpRecyclerView or something like that.